# Showing changes without refreshing in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, refresh

I'm so new in VueJS and still don't control much of its funcionalities,

I'm trying when I update or delete something in my window not need to refresh to see the changes...how can I do it, please?

My functions work perfectly in my controller, just need to solve the question of seeing changes.

Here I post my code if it helps...thank you very much!!

### UpdateProfile.vue:

```
<div class="field">
            <label class="label">Schedules</label>
            <!--Edit and Delete Schedules-->
            <div v-for="schedule in sortedDays(data.schedulesDisplayed)" class="control">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label class="label">Week Day: {{schedule.week_day}}</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="row">
                                Opening Time: <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Pub schedules" v-model="schedule.opening_time">
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="row">
                                Closing Time: <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Pub schedules" v-model="schedule.closing_time">
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="buttons is-left">
                            <div class="button is-info" @click="updatePubSchedule(schedule)">
                                <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-save fa-lg"></i></span>
                                <span>Save</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="button is-danger" @click="deletePubSchedule(schedule)">
                                <span class="icon"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></span>
                                <span>Delete Schedule</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

updatePubSchedule(schedule){
            var instance = this;

            this.api.put('/pubschedules/update/' + this.data.id, schedule).then(response => {
                console.log(schedule);
                //data = response.data;
                instance = response.data;
            });
        },

 deletePubSchedule(schedule){
            var instance = this;

            this.api.delete('/pubschedules/delete/' + this.data.id, schedule).then(response => {
                //data = response.data;
                instance = response.data;
            });
        },
```

And in my controller:

```
/**
 * @param Pub $pub
 */
public function updatePubSchedule(Pub $pub)
{
    //json_die(request()->all());

    Schedule::where([
                        ['pub_id','=', $pub->id],
                        ['week_day' ,'=', request()->get('week_day')]
    ])->update(request()->all());
}

/**
 * @param Pub $pub
 */
public function deletePubSchedule(Pub $pub)
{
    Schedule::where([
        ['pub_id','=', $pub->id],
        ['week_day' ,'=', request()->get('week_day')]
    ])->delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you get your initial data but you can have a GET request that gets fresh data from the laravel after you update/delete initial data.

With the response from that request you can update your **data.schedulesDisplayed** prop.

**Important!** You need to set the `:key` attribute in the div that uses `v-for` rendering like this

```
<div v-for="(schedule, index) in sortedDays(data.schedulesDisplayed)" :key="index" class="control">
```

I used the **index** for the sake of this example but you should use a unique property of **sortedDays** return.